# Is there any solution for mobile grid (native) - 30 column?

Tags: mobile, android, ios, data-tables, native-app

I was looking ux patterns on internet but couldn't find specific solution for it.

I have more than 25 column grid which would like to show on mobile native app. Customer is interested to show all the columns, so anyone has experience/pattern for mobile to provide solution for such kind of grid.

Comment: Do you mean a grid ad in: a layout system or a table must accomodatie 25 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine a few most important columns in your grid and show them by default. To view more information allow a user to select what he wants to see:
[image]

When user clicks on "Select columns" dropdown:
[image]